# Is it possible to see my deleted messages on Facebook Messenger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I am not talking about archived messages. Is there a way to see them after they have been deleted? Is there a special software that could do this?

Comment: My sense is that you'd have to contact Facebook directly.  There's no way to get them back from a local copy or anything because the data is living on their servers.

Answer (score 2):

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/messenger-app/540897679352879):

> **No, you can't retrieve deleted messages or conversations.** Deleting a message permanently removes it from your inbox.
>
> Keep in mind that deleting a message or conversation from your inbox won't delete it from your friend's inbox. It isn't possible to delete sent or received messages from a friend's inbox.